# Configure https in nginx with php, the php is not interpreted

Tags: php, nginx, https

When I try accessing: https://www.mysite.com, it downloads a php file, however when I access https://www.mysite.com/index.php, there is no problem.

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name www.mysite.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

root /var/www/mysite.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}
```

}

So, php is not interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problems before, where the page would just show the source code for index.php whenever a 404 error occurred.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

Try this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
error_page    404 = /index.php?$query_string;
```

If the problem still occurs, try this adding this:

```
location ~ ^/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php =404;
}
```

This is an ugly hack, but it worked for me on my old server. Haven't needed it in my new setup for some reason.